# Create ActivityParty in CRM without early bound Entities

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

As a requirement I cannot use the early bound context created with "CrmSvcUtil". The problem is that a new phonecall activity expects two fields ('from' and 'to') which are `Entities` of type `activityparty`. The standard XRM/CRM namespace does not contain a class similar to `ActivityParty` created with the Utility.

I tried filling it with an EntityCollection but then the field will be empty. Next I tried to recreate the structure of a working phonecall activity. `EntityCollection` "*activityparty*" -> with one `Entity` "*activityparty*" -> with `EntityReference` attribute "*partyid*" -> the entity ref (e.g. "contact" and the contact's id). But it simply does not work.

How can I create an ActivityParty (or better a phonecall Activity) with the "normal" `Entitiy` classes?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I'm right you don't need to use an `EntityCollection` but an array of `Entity`

To create a phone call with late bound syntax will be:

```
Entity from1 = new Entity("activityparty");
Entity to1 = new Entity("activityparty");
Entity to2 = new Entity("activityparty"); // two contacts inside the to field

from1["partyid"]= new EntityReference("systemuser", userId);
to1["partyid"]= new EntityReference("contact", contact1Id);
to2["partyid"]= new EntityReference("contact", contact2Id);

Entity phonecall = new Entity("phonecall");

phonecall["from"] = new Entity[] { from1 };
phonecall["to"] = new Entity[] { to1, to2 };
// other phonecall fields

Guid phonecallId = service.Create(phonecall);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though I upvoted the answer but I had simmilar problem with serialization of ActivityParty. I came to solution that doesn't require you to give up on early bound entities.

what you need to do is something like this:

```
IEnumerable<ActivityParty> party = new [] { new ActivityParty { PartyId="", EntityLogicalName="..." } }; 
phonecall["to"] = new EntityCollection(party.Select(x => x.ToEntity<Entity>).ToList());
```

(I didn't test the code and wrote it from the air but you should feel the idea)

Comment: thanks for the upvote :) in your code you have a mixed of early and late bound. For a full example of both styles not mixed you can check my blog: http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/08/dynamics-crm-special-data-types.html

Comment: yes I did, becasue phonecall.To is of a type IEnumerable<ActivityParty> which causes problem with serialization (I had some error: 
Inner Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'MyNamespace.ActivityParty' with data contract name 'ActivityParty:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNameSpace' is not expected) and it caused me a headache. funny thing it worked on my dev machine where I have .net 4.5 and the error only occurs on test server where they still have .net 4.0). The way I did it fixed the problem. But I know it looks ugly a bit.

Comment: phonecall.To is an array of ActivityParty (or an array of Entity if you prefer)

Comment: umm.. sorry misunderstanding again, you're right I messed up - just realized that when I read it second time

Answer (score 0):

I vote for TrN because i was looking for any kind of example, and it's the only early bound example that i could find.

His example Actually helped me create an PhoneCall entity that had the Attribute "From" pointing to the Lead that actually made the call. I never fully understood the `IEnumerable<ActivityParty>` enumerator. Thanks to TrN i understand it enough to use it.

Here is my code regarding the **PhoneCall activity** that I've tested and it works. Everytime an existing Lead calls. The PhoneCall activity gets saved with the correct Attribute values linked to the correct Lead.

```
IEnumerable<ActivityParty> party = new[] { new ActivityParty { LogicalName = ActivityParty.EntityLogicalName , PartyId = eref2  } };


                    Console.WriteLine("Logging activity to {0}", firstName);
                    Console.WriteLine("... \n" );
                    PhoneCall newCall = new PhoneCall { Description = "Missed phone call from this lead", DirectionCode = true, RegardingObjectId = eref2,
                        Subject = "Missed Call", PhoneNumber = MissedCall, OwnerId = User, From = party };



                    Guid newCallId = service.Create(newCall);

                Console.WriteLine("Log successfully created \n \n ");
```

As i said, For Kirschi this isnt the real solution given his requirement of not having any context. But anyone who wants/can use provided context and is curious how the `IEnumerable<ActivityParty>` works, this might help them to create a proper PhoneCall Activity.

Answer (score -1):

Here is working code for the same. Feel free to reach out if anyone faces any issue.

```
private static void fetchRelatedPhoneCalls(IPluginExecutionContext context, IOrganizationService service, Guid yourGuid, Entity opp)
{
    string strFetchPhoneCalls = string.Format(FetchQuery.bringFetchQueryForPhoneCalls(),yourGuid);
    EntityCollection entPhoneCalls = (EntityCollection)service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(strFetchPhoneCalls));

    if (entPhoneCalls != null && entPhoneCalls.Entities.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < entPhoneCalls.Entities.Count; i++)
        {
            Entity entPhoneCall = (Entity)entPhoneCalls.Entities[i];

            string[] strAttributesPCtoRemove = new string[] { "createdon", "createdbyname", "createdby"
                            ,"modifiedon", "modifiedby" ,"regardingobjectid","owninguser"
                            ,"activityid", "instancetypecode", "activitytypecode" // PhoneCall Skip
            };

            Entity entNewPhoneCall = this.CloneRecordForEntity("phonecall", entPhoneCall, strAttributesPCtoRemove);
            entNewPhoneCall["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference(context.PrimaryEntityName, context.PrimaryEntityId);
            entNewPhoneCall["to"] = this.getActivityObject(entNewPhoneCall, "to");
            entNewPhoneCall["from"] = this.getActivityObject(entNewPhoneCall, "from");

            service.Create(entNewPhoneCall);
        }
    }
}

private static Entity CloneRecordForEntity(string targetEntityName, Entity sourceEntity, string[] strAttributestoRemove)
{
    Entity clonedEntity = new Entity(targetEntityName);
    AttributeCollection attributeKeys = sourceEntity.Attributes;
    foreach (string key in attributeKeys.Keys)
    {
        if (Array.IndexOf(strAttributestoRemove, key) == -1)
        {
            if (!clonedEntity.Contains(key))
            {
                clonedEntity[key] = sourceEntity[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return clonedEntity;
}

private static EntityCollection getActivityObject(Entity entNewActivity, string activityFieldName)
{
    Entity partyToFrom = new Entity("activityparty");
    partyToFrom["partyid"] = ((EntityReference)((EntityCollection)entNewActivity[activityFieldName]).Entities[0].Attributes["partyid"]);

    EntityCollection toFrom = new EntityCollection();
    toFrom.Entities.Add(partyToFrom);

    return toFrom;
}
```